# Compiling Error in Python when accessing .glade File

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, gtk3, glade

I'm learning to make GUI using python 2.7 together with Glade to make the task easier. I use PyCharm in a Windows 7 machine.
I'm following a tutorial to make a simple window ([link](http://gnipsel.com/glade/glade02a.html)). The tutorial is the number 2 and is divided in part A and B. In A it shows how work in Glade environment and in B it shows how use python to access .glade file and show the simple interface.
I complete the tutorial 1 without any problem.

Here is a image of my code and the error I get.[Print from screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhQ3c.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue is a bug in Glade, the error message occurs due the line 175 in XML file generated by the Glade. This line disable a small separation between two boxes in the "About window", when I manually enable this separation in Glade, the line disapper and the program work's fine. Instead of do this, when I delete the line 175 directly in the XML file generated , the program also  works fine. Except by a warning message when the "About window" is opened. But doesn't seem to interfere in the code's functionality.